# Theorem numbering in \appendix includes "Appendix" just before the counter

Tags: numbering, theorems, appendices

I am using a bespoke document class which I have not developed.

When declaring theorems or lemmas within the main body, the counter is correctly associated to the subsection number with no further qualifiers e.g. **Theorem 1.2**.

However when doing so in the appendix, I am getting the following format e.g. **Lemma Appendix A.2**. The word "Appendix" is undesired in here.

**How can I get rid of it?** Not sure where I need to look at in the bespoke class; the following definitions are included:

```latex
\def\@xthm#1#2{\@begintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{}\ignorespaces}
\def\@ythm#1#2[#3]{\@opargbegintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#3}\ignorespaces}
```

as well as for `\@begintheorem`; `\@opargbegintheorem`; and `\@endtheorem`. But I see no counter definition.

---

**Edit**: I have included some MWE as suggested, where I display the relevant definitions for `theorem`-like environments. But because I am using a proprietary bespoke class, as specified at the top of the question, the below code *does not* reproduce the error.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\def\@xthm#1#2{\@begintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{}\ignorespaces}
\def\@ythm#1#2[#3]{\@opargbegintheorem{#2}{\csname
        the#1\endcsname}{#3}\ignorespaces}%
%
\let\Theoremfont\itshape
%
\let\Theoremheadfont\bfseries
%
\def\@begintheorem#1#2#3{\par\addvspace{8pt plus3pt minus2pt}%
    \noindent{\csname#1headfont\endcsname#1\ \ignorespaces#3 #2.}%
    \csname#1font\endcsname\hskip6pt\ignorespaces}
\def\@endtheorem{\par\addvspace{8pt plus3pt minus2pt}\@endparenv}
%
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\par\addvspace{6pt plus3pt minus2pt}%
    \def\@tempa{#3}%
    \noindent{\bf #1 #2 \ifx\@tempa\empty\unskip\else\unskip\ (#3).\fi\hskip.5em}\csname#1font\endcsname\ignorespaces
    %   \noindent{\bf #2 \ifx\@tempa\empty\unskip\else\unskip: #3\fi\hskip1em}\it
    \ignorespaces}

%
\def\@endtheorem{\par\addvspace{6pt plus3pt minus2pt}}
%
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%
\newif\iflogo
\def\prbox{\par
    \vskip-\lastskip\vskip-\baselineskip\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{\vrule width5pt height5pt depth0pt}}}\global\logofalse}

\begin{document}
    \appendix
    \section{Appendix}
    \subsection{First Appendix}
    \begin{theorem}
        Latex is useful.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did not include the class because the problem would not be reproducible, as I am having to use some bespoke template. I think the solution by jlab is probably the most hassle-free considering the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the full definitions set by the class, you can redefine the commands that print the numbers in the appendix:

```tex
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{lemma}}
```

Comment: Thank you @jlab. I was hoping for something "cleaner" i.e. a global setting but considering I am having to use some bespoke class with non-standard settings, this is probably the most effective solution all in all. Cheers.